# input tag with accepts

Tags: html, input

I have a file to upload in my page.

```
<input type="file" id='fFile' name="template"/>
```

But I want it to show only rptdesign file. Could anyone please help?

Also I have added

```
<input type="file" id='fXls' name="template"
accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"/>
```

for xlsx but when the dialog box appears with All files and Xlsx in the dropdown but all All Files selected. Can Xlsx be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into MIME_Types:

```
<input accept="audio/*|video/*|image/*|MIME_type">
```

A list of different media MIME-types [here!](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

**Note:** The accept attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

**EDIT**

In your Tomcat configuration files, go to your web.xml.

If you scroll down you will find mime-type mapping. Here you can specify extensions for the server!

Example (web.xml):

```
<mime-mapping>
        <extension>asx</extension>
        <mime-type>video/x-ms-asf</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: i didnt find any mime types for rptdesign files.

Comment: Are you using tomcat by any chance? :) @Biswas

Comment: ya, i am using tomcat server for that :)

Answer (score 0):

In chrome its working fine and I found out that firefox are still working on it.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=826185